# How can I start a LIBGDX particle effect mid way through?

Tags: java, libgdx

Is it possible to start a particle effect mid way through? I have tried many variations of updating the particle effect/emitters upon initialisation. None of them seem to work. Has anyone managed to do this before? Thanks a lot!

```
    ParticleEffectPool.PooledEffect effect = particleEffectPool.obtain();
    effect.setPosition(posnX,posnY);

    float value = 1.5f;

    for(ParticleEmitter e: effect.getEmitters()){
        e.update(value);
        value+=1.5f;
    }
```

The above code doesn't draw all of the particles, but it does seem to update the them somewhat. Once the initial effect is over, it resets and then it looks fine

EDIT: I've found a little bit of a hack by doing the following code snippet 5 times upon initialisation of the particle effect. Still interested to see if someone has a better solution

```
 p.getEmitters().get(0).addParticle();
 p.update(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that all emitters in your `ParticleEffect` have the same duration:

```
ParticleEffectPool.PooledEffect effect = particleEffectPool.obtain();
effect.reset();
effect.setPosition(posnX,posnY);

//divide by 1000 to convert from ms to seconds
float effectDuration = effect.getEmitters().first().duration / 1000f;
float skipProgress = 0.5f;
effect.update(skipProgress * effectDuration);
```

Note, that if emitters have different duration, you probably would want to pick the max duration. Also, if your emitters have delays, you should take them into account too.

**Update**

This approach will not work as expected in case, when some of effect's properties change over time. So if you skip half of its duration, you don't take in account all changes that happened before. You just start from some state.

For example, let's say effect has duration = 10, and its velocity is 100 for the first 4 seconds, and after that velocity is 0. If you call `effect.update(5)`, i.e. just skip first 5 seconds, particles will have velocity = 0, they just won't "know", that they had to move for the first 4 seconds.

So, I guess the only workaround here, is to update the effect with small steps in a loop, instead of just updating for half of its duration in one call:

```
ParticleEffectPool.PooledEffect effect = particleEffectPool.obtain();
effect.reset();
effect.setPosition(posnX,posnY);

//divide by 1000 to convert from ms to seconds
float skipDuration = 0.5f * effect.getEmitters().first().duration / 1000f;
//I guess, to reduce number of iterations in a loop, you can safely use 
//a bit bigger stepDeltaTime, like 1 / 10f or bigger, but it depends on you effect;
//here I just use standard frame duration
final float stepDeltaTime = 1 / 60f;

while (skipDuration > 0) {
    float dt = skipDuration < stepDeltaTime ? skipDuration : stepDeltaTime;
    effect.update(dt);
    skipDuration -= stepDeltaTime;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I've tried your code and this was the following [result](https://imgur.com/a/28I3X). However, I wanted it to look like [this](https://imgur.com/a/Yhqfs).I don't know why your code doesn't give the desired effect - I have no delays and all emitters have the same duration.

Comment: It's really strange. Looks like the effect changes its position, particles' velocity, etc. If you don't change anything, only update it, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me, why exactly do you want the effect to start a particle effect mid way through?

Comment: Edited, try to reset right after particleEffectPool.obtain()

Comment: I agree, it is weird. No luck reseting the effect before setting the posn. I wanted it to seem as though the cart had been smoking for a while, rather than starting once the level began. The only thing I've managed to get working is what I've put in the EDIT section of my initial post. However, that feels like a hack!

Comment: Updated the answer once again, this should work. You don't really need to do anything with emitters directly, like p.getEmitters().get(0).addParticle();.

Comment: The updated code works nicely, although I'm not sure why we had to incrementally update the particle - why doesn't just effect.update(skipDuration) work? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Maybe my example was unclear. I'll try another, more abstract) When you update an effect with some time step, you have information about effect's state before the step, and after it. You don't know what was the state at any moment INSIDE the time step. So if the time step is too big, you risk to lose too much information about how exactly the effect have been changing state, especially if a lot of effect parameters change over time.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense now. Thanks for your help